# Why can't I ping the outside world from my ubuntu box?

Tags: networking, ubuntu

I can't seem to ping or ssh to an outside domain. Internal IP addresses work fine. It resolves the IP address, so I don't think it is DNS. The local host seems to intercept my requests somehow. Curl works. This is ubuntu server 10.4. My internal IP is 192.168.1.14.

**EDIT: I stopped ufw via `stop ufw` and added some more info below.**

```
matt@valkyrie:~$ ping google.com
PING google.com (173.194.33.104) 56(84) bytes of data.
From valkyrie (192.168.1.14) icmp_seq=1 Destination Port Unreachable
From valkyrie (192.168.1.14) icmp_seq=2 Destination Port Unreachable
From valkyrie (192.168.1.14) icmp_seq=3 Destination Port Unreachable
From valkyrie (192.168.1.14) icmp_seq=4 Destination Port Unreachable
From valkyrie (192.168.1.14) icmp_seq=5 Destination Port Unreachable
From valkyrie (192.168.1.14) icmp_seq=6 Destination Port Unreachable
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, +6 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4999ms
```

Default route

```
root@valkyrie:/etc/nagios3# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
```

Traceroute

```
root@valkyrie:/etc/nagios3# traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (173.194.33.104), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  valkyrie (192.168.1.14)  0.409 ms  0.459 ms  0.481 ms
```

iptables

```
root@valkyrie:/etc/nagios3# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
blockcontrol_in  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW mark match !0x14 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
blockcontrol_fw  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW mark match !0x14 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
blockcontrol_out  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW mark match !0x14 

Chain blockcontrol_fw (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            mark match 0xa 
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             arbiter             
RETURN     all  --  192.168.1.0/24       192.168.1.0/24      
NFQUEUE    all  --  anywhere             anywhere            NFQUEUE num 92

Chain blockcontrol_in (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            mark match 0xa 
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  192.168.1.0/24       anywhere            
NFQUEUE    all  --  anywhere             anywhere            NFQUEUE num 92

Chain blockcontrol_out (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            mark match 0xa reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             arbiter             
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             192.168.1.0/24      
RETURN     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https 
RETURN     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:www 
NFQUEUE    all  --  anywhere             anywhere            NFQUEUE num 92
```

Comment: Oooh, looks like `REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            mark match 0xa reject-with icmp-port-unreachable` might have something to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you curl google? If so, it's likely either PING or ICMP is blocked outgoing. Determine which by trying to do a traceroute to google.com `traceroute google.com` and see if that also fails. Then check your software firewall - if you have iptables try `iptables -L` and paste the output, although Ubuntu might come with a different firewall by default. If that has nothing, contact your hosting provider or ISP and ask them if they are blocking ICMP outbound.

Comment: Curl works. It's not the ISP because I can perform all these tasks on my macbook. I'll paste in my traceroute and iptables in my original question.

Comment: This is almost definitely iptables

Comment: I had to delete two entries: `NFQUEUE    all  --  anywhere             anywhere            NFQUEUE num 92` and `REJECT all -- anywhere anywhere mark match 0xa reject-with icmp-port-unreachable`

Comment: I may be spamming at this point, but it seems *moblock* a P2P protection daemon was inserting all the iptable records causing the problems.

Comment: What about if I'm geting this error? `traceroute to google.com (172.217.8.206), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets send: Operation not permitted`. `iptables -L` gives `bash: iptables: command not found` even though I have iptables installed with `sudo apt install iptables`

Comment: Try sudo iptables. Iptables is installed into /sbin/iptables which is only root accessible by default.

Answer (score 1):

There's a misconfiguration somewhere, probably on the server or the router, as ICMP doesn't use ports but your ping response indicates "port unreachable". You can run a packet capture on the server and ping again and look at the ICMP code returned with the response to determine what's happening. If it is in fact code 3 (port unreachable) then there's something flaky somewhere.

I would almost think it's a routing loop but that would typically generate a "TTL expired in transit" response.

Answer (score 0):

there's likely a firewall between you and your ISP blocking ICMP communication, or your ISP is having issues.

Answer (score 0):

You could see this if you don't have a default gateway set.  Try either `route -n` if you have old net-tools or `ip route` from the newer iproute2 package to see your routing table.

Comment: added the output of `route -n` to my question

Comment: What if I'm getting `bash: route: command not found`?

Comment: Better to stop using `netstat` and `route` entirely; they have been deprecated since before this answer was originally posted, which is why `net-tools` is no longer installed by default.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but I just ran in to the same issue on Ubuntu.

To fix, allow the range of outgoing ports 33434 to 33523 over UDP.

You are likely using ufw as your firewall on Ubuntu as it comes standard, the command to open up these ports on ufw is:

```
sudo ufw insert 1 allow out 33434:33523/udp
```

Then you should be able to run the plain traceroute command with no flags like:

```
traceroute yahoo.com
```

If the command runs without displaying an error but only shows empty responses or an asterix for each response you may need to disable your VPN while you run the traceroute

Also, if you are using IPv6 and the traceroute command is showing an IPv6 address along with the error message you can try forcing it to use IPv4 with the command flag "-4" typed as:

```
traceroute -4 yahoo.com
```